# Text in the message box should be the next next lines

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

Basically i display the some text in the `MessageBox` with `Ok` and `Cancel` button in WindowPhone 7.1.

I need the requirement like the below.

Some text will be here....

Property:value...

Actually we can simply the text in the MessageBox, but how can i add the linebreak between the text in the MessageBox.. Is there any way to do this in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use Environment.Newline for line breaks

```
string msg = "Text here" + Environment.NewLine + "some other text";
```

Comment: Actually, from what I've seen it only expects `\n`, not a full newline. A little-known feature of message boxes is that you can copy its text out (on PC anyway) by pressing `Ctrl+C`, and when you do that you'll see that all `\n` characters will be replaced by a full `Environment.NewLine`. However, if you used the full newline _already_, `\r\n`, then that will result in lines separated by `\r\r\n`, which will show as double lines in some applications.

Answer (score 8):

```
MessageBox.Show("Line 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line 2");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

\n or `<br />` for line Breaks. I am not sure if this will work:

Example:

```
string msg = "Some text will be here\nProperty:value";

MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

Comment: On windows it's `\r\n`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 MessageBox.Show("aa" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "bb");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a old post, but... If your text comes from resource file, none of the suggested solution works. In VS resource editor, you have to use **Shift+Enter** to enter new line. All others will just show as raw text like "\n" or, "\r\n" or "<br />".

Answer (score 1):

### There are 2 options `\n` and `Environment.NewLine`

Option 1: `\n`

I don't know if this work for sure on Windows phone but I think it would

`\n` - New line. Place as much as sentences as you want

```
MessageBox.Show("Some Text Here In The Line NO.1\nSome Text Here In Line NO.2");
```

Will show:

```
Some Text Here In The Line NO.1
Some Text Here In Line NO.2
```

OR

```
MessageBox.Show("Some Text Here In The Line NO.1 +"\n" + "Some Text Here In Line NO.2");
```

Will show the same as the first one:

```
Some Text Here In The Line NO.1
Some Text Here In Line NO.2
```

Option 2: `Environment.NewLine`

`Environment.NewLine` - New line. Place as much as sentences as you want

```
MessageBox.Show("Some Text Here In The Line NO.1" + Environment.NewLine + "Some Text Here In Line NO.2");
```

Will show the same as the first one:

```
Some Text Here In The Line NO.1
Some Text Here In Line NO.2
```

From [msdn.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The functionality provided by NewLine (Environment.NewLine) is often what is meant by the terms newline, line feed, line break, carriage return, CRLF, and end of the line.

I prefer \n because is shorter and faster but whatever you like.

Comment: Just `\n` is more correct too, internally; the message box seems to replace all `\n` characters in the given string by the platform's `Environment.NewLine` when copying the text box info (ctrl+c), so with full `\r\n` line breaks in the initial text you'll end up with messed up `\r\r\n` in the copied text.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *very* **very** large message to display, use:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                            "Line 1",
                            "Line 2",
                            "Line 3"));
```