# C++ Identifier "Environment" is undefined

Tags: c++, newline, messagebox

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156159/text-in-the-message-box-should-be-the-next-next-lines) post, I tried to include a new line in a MessageBox like below:

```
std::wstring msg = "Text here" + Environment.NewLine + "some other text";

MessageBox(nullptr, msg.c_str(), L"Hello World!", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

But compiler generated the error:

> E0020: identifier "Environment" is undefined

I tried including `<windows.system.h>`, but it did nothing.

Project type: C++ ATL

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: shouldn't it be Environment::NewLine (not knowing the actual package...)

Comment: @user2717954 then compiler says `E0276 - name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name`. :-(

Comment: sorry was just guessing :) so what IS Enviroment?

Comment: as far as i remember Environment.NewLine is from .net framework isn't it?

Comment: @user2717954 Sorry I didn't understand what you said. What did you mean? Compiler is Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: @RomanAnanyev I already installed almost all .NET packages from installer when installing Visual Studio.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` is used in C#, as in that post in C++ it is `Environment::NewLine`

Comment: @meJustAndrew OK, I thought it is C++ and not asked because of being a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) in your native C++ application because it is a .NET construct. For a newline character in standard C++ use `std::endl` or a `'\n'` character:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "This prints\n text on two lines.";
}
```

For a newline in the [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI function use `\r\n` characters. Your code should be:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
int main(){
    std::wstring msg = L"Text here \r\n some other text";
    MessageBox(NULL, msg.c_str(), L"Hello World!", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Comment: When I try to use `+ "\n" +` for a new line, compiler says: `E2140 - expression must have integral or unscoped enum type`.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.NewLine` is used in C#, as in that post in C++ it is `Environment::NewLine`

For a new line you can use `"\n"`

Comment: But why compiler says `Environment` isn't a class or a namespace name? Isn't it available in C++? Or do I need to add a `using` directive like `using namespace Environment`?

Comment: @GTAVLover you don't have the right project type, to use Environment, you will need a .net based project, like CLI/CLR

Comment: Thanks , then is `"\n"` the only way to use a newline in an ATL project?

Comment: @GTAVLover there may be wrappers around this, but it is the most common way.

Comment: But can I do it like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-compile-mfc-and-atl-code-by-using-clr)?

Comment: @GTAVLover you can build indeed the ALT project on .net as a CLR project, but only for Environment.Newline, there will be no worth for the effort.

Comment: Thanks for important information about project types.